Is there an integral fusion category of the Ising type?
In [EGNO, Section 8.27.3], we read:

Any braided fusion category ${\mathcal C}$ is obtained from a weakly anisotropic
category (namely, the core of ${\mathcal C}$) using ﬁnite groups (via the
equivariantization and extension procedures). Thus, the classiﬁcation
of braided fusion categories reduces to that of weakly anisotropic ones.

Note that weakly anisotropic refers to having no Tannakian subcategories stable under the group of braided autoequivalences.
A weakly anisotropic fusion category ${\mathcal C}$ falls into one of the following types:

ordinary, if ${\mathcal C}_{pt} ∩ ({\mathcal C}_{pt} )' = {\mathcal C}' =  \mathrm{Vec}$,
super, if ${\mathcal C}_{pt} ∩ ({\mathcal C}_{pt} )' = {\mathcal C}' =  \mathrm{sVec}$,
Ising, if ${\mathcal C}'=\mathrm{Vec}$ and ${\mathcal C}_{pt} ∩ ({\mathcal C}_{pt} )' = \mathrm{sVec}$,

where ${\mathcal C}_{pt}$ denotes the maximal pointed fusion subcategory of ${\mathcal C}$.
Examples of braided fusion categories of the Ising type include the so-called Ising categories (see [DGNO, Appendix B]). These categories are weakly integral but not integral. This brings us to the following:
Question: Is there an integral braided fusion category of the Ising type?
Warning: In the literature, the notation Ising-type modular category may also specifically refer to the Ising categories (in [DGNO, Appendix B]) and not to the more general concept of fusion categories of the Ising type (from [DGNO, Definition 5.30]).
The definition of Ising type above encompasses non-degenerate (thus modular, in the integral case) and weakly anisotropic.
Theorem ([Nat,Theorem 4.1]): A weakly group-theoretical (WGT) integral weakly anisotropic braided fusion category is pointed.
Corollary: An integral braided fusion category of the Ising type (if any) would
be non-WGT.
proof: By the previous theorem, if it is WGT then it is pointed, i.e. ${\mathcal C}={\mathcal C}_{pt}$. Thus, by Ising assumption, $\mathrm{Vec}=\mathrm{sVec}$, contradiction. $\square$
Motivation: A negative answer to above question would positively answer Question 2 in this post (i.e. the WGT problem reduces to the simple case), for the following reason:
Let ${\mathcal C}$ be a non-WGT integral fusion category. The core ${\mathcal D}$ of the center $\mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$ is a weakly anisotropic braided fusion category, so is of ordinary, super, or Ising type. By [DGNO, Corollary 5.15], ${\mathcal D}$ is modular and thus cannot be of super type. I expect that ${\mathcal D}$ remains integral and non-WGT. If ${\mathcal D}$ is of ordinary type, then by [DGNO, Theorem 5.33], it must contain a non-WGT simple integral component in its Deligne tensor product decomposition. Therefore, we can assume it is of Ising type. However, if a braided fusion category of the Ising type cannot be integral, then the task is complete.
Note that, according to Lagrange's theorem [EGNO, Theorem 7.17.6], an integral fusion category of the Ising type must be even-dimensional. Therefore, the above argument already provides a positive answer to Question 2 in this post for the odd-dimensional case.

References
[DGNO] Drinfeld, Vladimir; Gelaki, Shlomo; Nikshych, Dmitri; Ostrik, Victor. On braided fusion categories. I. Selecta Math. (N.S.) 16 (2010), no. 1, 1--119.
[EGNO] Etingof, Pavel; Gelaki, Shlomo; Nikshych, Dmitri; Ostrik, Victor. Tensor categories. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 205. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2015. xvi+343 pp.
[Nat] Natale, Sonia. The core of a weakly group-theoretical braided fusion category. Internat. J. Math. 29 (2018), no. 2, 1850012, 23 pp.

ℂ is algebraically closed. ℝ is not. As a result, one gets simpler answers when classifying ℂ-algebras than when classifying ℝ-algebras. Given classification results for ℂ-algebras, one gets corresponding results for ℝ-algebras by Galois descent.  sVec_ℂ is algebraically closed. Vec_ℂ is not.  Classifying  sVec-linear categories often produces nicer answers than for Vec-linear categories. And given results for sVec-linear categories, one obtains corresponding results for Vec-linear categories by Galois descent (the Galois group is ℤ/2×Bℤ/2). I learned this from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06297

@AndréHenriques I was not familiar with the concept of a categorified field; it seems intriguing. However, I'm unsure how to apply it practically to the question at hand. Can you help?

Unlike (Vec_ℂ)-linear symmetric fusion categories, whose classification splits into 2 cases, (sVec_ℂ)-linear symmetric fusion categories are classified by finite groups. So the classification of Tannakian categories simplifies quite a bit when working (sVec_ℂ)-linearly. I'd be ready to bet that the classification of weakly anisotropic categories also simplifies when working over sVec_ℂ. To descend from an (sVec_ℂ)-linear statement to a (Vec_ℂ)-linear statement, you'll have to understand Bℤ/2-actions on such categories. A Bℤ/2-action is just the data of a "grading involution" for each object...

Unless I am mistaken, the Tannakian fusion categories over Vec_ℂ are equivalent to Rep(G). In contrast, the Tannakian fusion categories over sVec_ℂ are the super-Tannakian fusion categories over Vec_ℂ, which are classified as Rep(G,z) by Deligne. However, the class of braided fusion categories of the form Rep(G,z) is more complicated than just Rep(G).

Sorry, instead of writing "the classification of Tannakian categories simplifies quite a bit when working (sVec_ℂ)-linearly", I should have written "the classification of symmetric fusion categories simplifies quite a bit when working (sVec_ℂ)-linearly".
